# Is grouping columns in google stacked column chart possible?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, stacked-chart, column-chart

i have Google column chart, stacked. There are final horizontal axis ticks (A,B,C...J).
I need to represent groups of this columns, with some aditional data (percentage of total). 
So, groups should be (A,B,C,D), (D,E,F,G), (G,H,I,J), please look at attached image.

So far, only thing i managed to do is make 3 separate charts, one for each group.

Can this columns be grouped inside one chart?
[image: grouped stacked column chart]

Comment: there aren't any standard options but you can manually add to the chart, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996758/5090771)...