# Google Charts with 3 level groupings

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have following dataset for creating a stacked bar chart:

```
**Year  Product     Buyer A Buyer B Buyer C**
2008    Product A   100     100     20
        Product B   55              15
        Product C                   90
2009    Product A   80      30      78
        Product B   59              54
        Product C           26
```

I wish to generate a stacked bar chart like this:
[image]

This is easily achievable in excel. But could not do it in Google Charts.

Comment: there aren't any standard options for this, you would have to build your -- either using your own adjacent html, or modifying the chart's svg, on it's `'ready'` event, similar to one of these answers --> [google Line chart with double label on X axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996758/5090771) -- [Hierarchies graphs in google charts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40240392/5090771)